# Continuous deployment with Travis and Modulus

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, modulus.io

I am trying to implement a continuous deployment of my Node.js/Express app to Modulus using Travis CI. What I want to achieve is that after I push my code to the Github master branch, Travis picks it up and runs the builds and upon successfully doing so automatically re-deploys it to Modulus.

The initial deploy to Modulus was successful, however, it didn't run through Travis but was deployed using the Modulus CLI. Now, with the below settings in place I try to get automatic continuous deployment to run.

.travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- '0.10'
deploy:
  provider: modulus
  project_name: myapp
  api_key:
    secure: G/j0jvYemr1QW4URHIvsBdHhW6g+O...
```

Yet, when I make changes to my project and push it to Github, Travis tells you everything passed. However, the project is never really redeployed on Modulus.

Snippet from Travis-CI.org

```
The command "npm test" exited with 0.
Fetching: dpl-1.7.8.gem (100%)

Installing deploy dependencies
Preparing deploy
Deploying application
Already up-to-date!
# HEAD detached at c521c41
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (e278ref0ff14a85e3eb27d74bbfdfa6321a7829d)
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

What point am I missing? Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with Travis' dpl tool which is what does the deployments. The modulus deployment bit was working at one point, but something that isn't very apparent from within dpl has regressed it.

There's an open issue for this on GitHub: https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/issues/207